# Rails: Form Select From Array/List Instance Variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I have a rails app where in a form, I have a form select (drop down list). 
For example the user can select from 1,2,3,4,5

Say for example I had these values stored in an array as an instance variable like:

> @formlist = [1,2,3,4,5]

How can I simply put the array into the form select helper rather than listing each item separately. At the moment my code is:

> ```
> <tr>
>   <th><%= f.label(:heat_level, "Heat Level") %></th>
>   <td><%= f.select(:heat_level,{ 1 => "1", 2 => "2", 3 => "3", 4 => "4", 5 => "5"}) %></td>
> </tr>
> ```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

this should work:

```
f.select(:heat_level, @formlist.map { |value| [ value, value ] })
```

some explanation:

form `select` can handle both hash-like and array-like options list.
Meaning, both
`{ 1 => "1", 2 => "2", 3 => "3", 4 => "4", 5 => "5"}`

and

`[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5]]`

will work.

`@formlist.map { |value| [ value, value ] }` does the latter

Comment: Just want to update for future users, the mapping is totally unnecessary for shallow arrays `f.select(:heat_level, @formlist)` is gonna give you the exact same result